# Laravel Combine DB Queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to combine the following two queries into one?

```
$session_id = DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('id', '=', $access_token)->value('session_id');
$owner_id = DB::table('oauth_sessions')->where('id', '=', $session_id)->value('owner_id');
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JosephSilber - From the first query I get the session_id value and then I use this in the second query to be able to get the owner_id. I was hoping it would be possible to have the first query as a part of the second one. The tables do not have the same columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a subquery:

```php
$query = DB::table('oauth_sessions');

$query->where('oauth_sessions.id', function ($query) use ($access_token) {
    $query->from('oauth_access_tokens')
          ->where('oauth_access_tokens.id', $access_token)
          ->select('session_id');
});

$owner_id = $query->value('owner_id');
```

You can chain it all instead of using 3 separate statements. I just formatted it because I think it reads nicer this way.

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. Thank you the help.